# Cucumber/Capybara find() doesn't retry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm a few days into writing Cucumber/Capybara tests for the first time and I'm running into trouble.

I've got a `Login.feature` file with two features; one tests login attempts with invalid credentials, the other with valid ones. The former test completes successfully while the latter fails.

I'm testing them by looking for a Bootstrap `alert` that's rendered after each type of action. On a failed login the page is refreshed with the alert message. On a success the user is redirected to their home page where the alert is presented.

My issue seems to be that when looking for the "success" alert in the test with valid credentials it fails because the page hasn't loaded yet. I understand that the `find` method is supposed to continue looking for the given element over a period of time defined by `Capybara.default_wait_time`.

The following is simple test I'm using:

```
find('div.alert.alert-success')
```

This results in a `Capybara::ElementNotFound` error every time. I've set `default_wait_time` to different lengths (the longest being 500) but the error occurs instantly regardless. I've dug into the code for `find` and injected some output so I can see whether or not the block continues to be executed over that period of time - it seems to try once and stops when the exception is raised.

Am I looking at this the wrong way? From what I've read it isn't encouraged to explicitly wait for a period of time, but the default mechanism doesn't work for me.

Comment: have you tried with `expect(page).to have_selector('div.alert.alert-success')` ? or maybe `expect(page).to have_selector('#flash_notice')` . It would be better if you post your html code

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: I have tried the `have_selector` approach as well, with the same result.

I'm not sure which driver I'm using. I haven't modified it so I suppose whichever driver is used by default with the Cucumber v2.4.0 gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default driver in Capybara is rack-test which doesn't do any waiting because it doesn't support JS or any other type of asynchronous behavior.  It sounds like your alerts are either rendered by JS (which won't happen with the rack-test driver), are hidden until being shown by JS (won't happen) or your credentials aren't actually valid.  You can check what html is being rendered by looking at `page.html'.   To use a different driver see Capybaras README - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers

Comment: Manipulating the tests a bit confirms that somehow the credentials are invalid, even though I'm using the same credentials when logging in manually.

Comment: @RyanDurel  When logging in manually to the test environment?  Tests run in the test environment while you're normally working in the dev environment, each have their own database instance and in tests you need to generate the records needed for each test using factories or fixtures.

Comment: You're right, that was something I didn't realize. I needed to make some changes to the test environment to match dev, though I'm still running into issues. It's more to do with how our project is set up.